# ASP.NET Core 7 IdentityServer4 HttpContext.User is null when accessed through alternative domain names

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an Angular app with an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API backend hosted on an azure app service, using IdentityServer4 for the JWT based authentication.

The app can be accessed via either a custom domain name or through a standard azure domain `website123456.azurewebsites.net`.

Relevant code from `Startup.cs` (`ConfigureServices` method)

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("CanPurge", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator")));
```

And `Configure` method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Things work well if the app is only accessed through a single domain - `HttpContext.User` property is not null and contains the user object for the currently logged in user. Now, if you then access the app through the other Url - Authentication works and JWT is issued - however the `HttpContext.User` is null when one of the API methods is invoked with the JWT token.

The API method in question is protected by the `[Authorize]` attribute, which does authenticate the request successfully. It does not matter which Url is used first, trying to access the app through the other Url after that will always produce this behaviour.

Google searches in regards to this issue did not yield anything useful.

Comment: I did a few blog posts about troubleshooting ASP.NET Core API problems here: https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/ and https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons based on different things across your architecture.

Try enabling a detailed debug log to find out the root cause.

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Debug"
    }
  }
```